# Finding largest number of similar elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have been stuck on this for a while now.

```
list= [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

How would I find the largest number of recurring elements? For instance for the list above, this would be 3 because there are three instances of [a,b,c,d] in the list.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']]

print max(list1.count(e) for e in list1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't believe I didn't think of this myself.